# How to reinsert a value on onclick inside a page?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would know how to take the value on onclik for inject inside a sql request.

This code below create a link. When I click on the link a specific table appear

```
$value can two elements
$value['name']
$value['option_id']

  $i = 0;

  foreach($option_attributes_name as $value) {
    $content .=      '<li class="col-md-12"><a class="showTabOption nav-link" data-tableid="' . $i . '" data-toggle="tooltip" data-target="#section_ProductsOptionApp_content" href="'. CLICSHOPPING::link('index.php?&pID='.  $_GET['pID'] .'#tab-option'. $i .'&toto=' . $value['option_id']) .'"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i> '. $value['name'] .'</a></li>';
    $i++;
  }
```

In my table I have a specific dropdown to display information.
Currently it take all informations by the mysql request, but than I tried to make, it's a dropdown must take only the information on the value `onclick ( .'&toto=' . $value['option_id'])`

On onclick, how to take the value `'&toto=' . $value['option_id']` to reinject inside the request.
Ajax page ?

I don't know if I am clear. If not I will complete this explanation.

Thank you.